How to receive the file and data(json) from javascript by FastAPI
I send the image file and json like this from javascript.
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("data",{"test":1});
//make jpg image from canvas.        
var image = ref_canvas_release.current.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.85);

//////// confirm and test the image file is correctly created. it created!
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = image;
a.download = 'test.jpg';
a.click();
////////

formData.append("file",image);

axios.post("/myuploader",formData,{headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/form-data'}}).then(res=>{
    console.log(res)
});

then my fastAPI is here.
from fastapi import FastAPI,UploadFile, File,Depends,status,Body,Request

@app.post('/myuploader')
def uploader(request: Request):
    print(request.query_params['data'])// key error 'data'
    return {"sending":"OK"}

I am not sure sender/receiver which or both are wrong.
Is there any general practice to send the file and json at once with form-data?

Thanks to @deceze
I am checking this documents.
https://www.starlette.io/requests/
and tried to change
@app.post('/myuploader')
def uploader(request: Request):
    print(request.stream())// 
    return {"sending":"OK"}

it shows <async_generator object Request.stream at 0xffffaeb19310>
I think I can step forward but still confused, how can I get the data and file from here or using Requst directly is not good idea?

Query parameters are in the URL following a ?. Post body data isn't query params.

Thank you very much i  updated my article. I think it suggests to make model for data, however accutually my data is not like {"test":1}, it's so complex and nested json. in this case How can I make the model?

The docs for starlette have the example. https://www.starlette.io/requests/

In your case, you are executing an async function in a sync function. That's why it shows the async_generator object. The solution is to await request.stream() and transform the function into async def uploader(request: Request)

Thank you @Isabi I should use the async as I useing the Request, and I can use some class like Body,pydantic etc,,, I am reading the documents around this and step forward.
